# How to add hours to Extjs date object

Tags: javascript, date, extjs5

I'm using extjs Date object in the format,
Fri Dec 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530
and  hour and minute format(11:30AM),
now how can I add 11.30am to date object?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Try to be more "complete" in your question, adding some code and with some more comment on your situation, thanks

Comment: i have date object( Fri Dec 18 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530) and i have string object (11:30Am) and i my output should be  Fri Dec 18 2015 00:11:30 GMT+0530.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your string is always in the format "HH:mm(a|p)m", you could do something like this:

```
var d = new Date(2015, 11, 18),
    s = '11:30am',
    isPM = s.indexOf('p') > -1,
    hours = parseInt(s.substr(0, 2), 10),
    minutes;

if (hours !== 12) {
    hours += isPM ? 12 : 0;
} else if (!isPM) {
    hours = 0;
}
minutes = parseInt(s.substr(3, 2), 10) + (hours * 60);


d = Ext.Date.add(d, Ext.Date.MINUTE, minutes);
console.log(d);
```